# Boosting algorithms only built with decision trees? why?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-modeling, boosting

My understanding of boosting is just training models sequentially and learning from its previous mistakes.

Can boosting algorithms be built with bunch of logistic regression? or logistic regression + decision trees?

If yes, I would like to know some papers or books that covers this topic in-depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boosting is not limited to tree-based models. Find some more information here:

> P. Bühlmann, T. Hothorn (2007), "[Boosting Algorithms: Regularization,
> Prediction and Model Fitting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2752.pdf)", Statistical Science 22(4), p. 477-505.

I implemented L2 linear regression boosting from Section 3.3 (p. 483) from the paper above in [this R-code](https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/l2_boosting.R). You may replace the L2 model by a logit model and see how it works.

Comment: Perfect! Will look into it, thanks!

Comment: @haneulkim BTW: the idea of combining estimators in a boosting estimator sounds interesting. IMO this would require averaging or stacking. I do not know if there is reasearch on this issue and/or if it brings an additional advantage. Would be happy to know if you gain some insights on this. Cheers…